# In Dash DataTable, how to edit a datatable from the same callback function where data and chart was rendered?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Wondering, i have an app where i load the chart and the table from a callback, now, once that happends i need to edit the table and get the chart changed, i was trying to use: derived_virtual_row_ids, but when i add this in the input and run the server i cannot edit and the server goes crazy like updating every 3 miliseconds,

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table as dt
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import pymysql as psql
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go



app2.layout = html.Div([
  dcc.Graph(id='table-editing-simple-output'),
  dcc.Interval(
    id='interval_',
    interval=2000 * 1000,
    n_intervals=0
    ),

 dt.DataTable(id="table",
             columns= [
                 {"name": x, "id": x} for x in params
             ],
            data=[],
            editable=True,
            sort_action="native",
            sort_mode='multi',
            row_selectable='multi',
            row_deletable=False,
            selected_rows=[],
            page_action='native',
            page_current= 0,
            page_size= 10,
            style_cell={
                    'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                    'height': 'auto',
            },
             ),

html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container')

])


@app2.callback(
  [Output('table-editing-simple-output', 'figure'), Output('table', 'data')],
  [Input("interval_", "n_intervals"), Input("table", "derived_virtual_row_ids"]
)
def display_output(rows):
  print(rows)
  dff = pd.DataFrame(rows)
  #df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[c['name'] for c in columns])
  qry = """SELECT * FROM new_schema_excel.xto_dvd_larger_file WHERE id < 25"""
  cnx = psql.connect(db='', user='', passwd='', port=3306)
  df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, cnx)
  x=df['id']
  y=df['End Depth']
  y2 = df['Start Depth']

  chart = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y
  )

  chart2 = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y2
  )


 data = [chart, chart2]

 layout = go.Layout(

    paper_bgcolor="white",
    plot_bgcolor='white',
    yaxis=dict(autorange='reversed'),
    hovermode='closest',
    xaxis=dict(showspikes=True),
    showlegend=True
 )
 return {
     'data': data, "layout": layout}, df.to_dict('records')
```

how can i accomplish to pass the data from datatable to the chart? do i need another callback?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The flow would have to be callback_1 updates the table, and callback_2 uses the table to update the chart.

Right now your table is using one of its own props as an input to update itself, and I'm actually amazed that Dash allowed. This is essentially a cyclical callback, which Dash usually won't allow because it would mean the callback calls itself in an infinite loop.

You also have two inputs to your existing callback, but only one arg in the function signature (`rows`). You should have a separate arg for each input (ex. `(n_intervals, rows)`).